# Some part of touch screen not working

Tags: android, boot, touchscreen

I am working in an android project targeted for Samsung Galaxy Tab E in Landscape.
The android application starts on boot(as per requirement), after booting, Android by default loads in portrait and switches to Landscape quickly.
The app is already started(Though screen is locked), but the working area in app would be only the width equal to the width in portrait.

This issue appears when screen is locked and orientation of tablet is set to Landscape.

With reference of attached picture in link https://i.stack.imgur.com/4K5Ul.png.
P : is screen when in portrait.
L : is screen when in Landscape.
A : is working portion of L (Whose width is equal with width in portrait mode)
B : is NON-working portion of landscape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is resolved, and I have explained my case and solution which might be useful for other developers with similar issue.

The issue was not with android application itself. The issue was because android starts my application before boot completion. In my project, android app would run in accessory mode, controlled from another device. 
Once the external device gets tablet during restart/power on, my android application starts to run before boot completion, I made another application (app of external device) which sends request to accessory device to sleep for a while when new device is found, so that tablet has enough time to boot and can start app.

Thank you!